# Find Sequence and Replace with subset

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have the following HTML within a multi-line text field.

href="/Pages/33/33998.aspx">(Answer 33998)

I need to remove the folder structure from the URL.
In my Regex I can find the match but I cant seem to get the replacement to work. Anyone have any suggestions?

Heres the start of my regex:

`<a href=\"\/Pages\/\d{1,}\/\d{3,}[.]aspx"></a>`

So I have this:

`Regex.Replace(Convert.ToString(properties.AfterProperties["Description"]), @"<a href='/Pages\/\d{1,}\/\d{3,}[.]aspx'>", "TEST", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`

Comment: [Don't use regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1895201)

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Regex.Replace` method and use groups to identify what you do need to preserve from your match, like below:

```
var sample = @"
    href='/Pages/33/33998.aspx'>(Answer 33998)
    href='/Pages/12345.aspx'>(no match)
    href='/Pages/lala/12345.aspx'>(no match)
    ";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(sample, 
//    |-- First group--|    |-- Second group --|
    @"(href=['""]/Pages)/\d+(/\d{3,}\.aspx['""])", "$1$2"));
// ------------- First and second groups -------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

You could, instead of using a regex, use a simple split by / and take the last array item.

```
string[] split = yourUri.Split("/");
```